# MongoDb aggregation $lookup and $project

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I just faced an interesting aggregation pipeline problem. as I'm new to it, I tried random things and didn't get the desired output. hope you people will help me to get a solution!

I have two collections,

collection a=>

```
{
    _id: 1,
    field1: "value1",
    field2: "value2
}
```

collection b=>

```
{
    _id: 101,
    collectionAId: 1,
    status: "active"
},
{
    _id: 102,
    collectionAId: 1,
    status: "inactive"
},
{
    _id: 102,
    collectionAId: 1,
    status: "expired"
}
```

and my goal is to get

```
{
    _id: 1,
    field1: "value1",
    field2: "value2,
    status: ["active", "inactive", "expired"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using `$map` combined with `$project`:

```js
db.a.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "b",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "collectionAId",
      "as": "output"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      field1: 1,
      field2: 1,
      status: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$output",
          "as": "v",
          "in": "$$v.status"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```